# not namespaced r class sources

Tags: java, android-studio

I just started learning Android development with the the book *Big Nerd Ranch 3rd Edition*, and in the first app/project you have to locate the `r.java` through **app/build/generated/source** but the only thing I could find was **BuildConfig**:

[image: shot1]

So I searched online, cleaned and rebuilt the project, and I was able to find `r.java` in a new place:

[image: shot2]

and it says not namespaced r class sources.

Even when I create a new project and don't do anything I have the same problem. I searched online and still don't know what I am doing wrong.

My question is how to find `r.java` in a new project without needing to clean and rebuild it? Do I need to delete and reinstall Android Studio?

Comment: Are you getting R cannot resolved ?

Comment: i dont see it somewhere.

Comment: How you create new project ?

Comment: File >New project i then press empty activity >next>i change the name to Geoquiz and i select android 4.0.3

Comment: check your `mainfest.xml` file, `MainActivity` class , `activity_main.xml`, and also `build.gradle` file. Do there have any errors ?

Comment: How do i check for errors each one?Should i press right click in each one and then validate?

Comment: Also how can they have errors i havent even touch them in the new project?

Comment: All these files will automatic created once new project is created..u can find them under `src` folder

Comment: No they dont have any error.Also i found posts with people with the same problem and they never found a solution.